# Rspec: how to test in isolation when using external dependencies in class constants

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

**EDIT**

In hindsight, it doesn't make any sense to call `These::Encryption` without actually requiring the dependency first, so the error I get about a missing constant is in fact a valid error.

And regarding `These::Helpers` - which can be optionally required - I *am* actually optionally including it by defining it before the rspec run begins.

I'll leave this question open for now, in case anyone has any more insights.

---

I have a method looking like this:

```ruby
module My
  class Service
    extend Forwardable

    def_delegators :@helpers, *These::Helpers.delegatable if defined?(These::Helpers)

    ENCRYPTED_KEY_PASSWORD = These::Encryption.get('my_password')
  end
end
```

It depends on two external classes `helper` and `encryption`. However, I want to test in full-isolation and stub out these two, as they have been tested elsewhere.

How can I do this in the context of the class?

The problem I am facing is that the class gets loaded when I `require` it, which triggers both the `if defined?` and `#get` methods, both failing, because I haven't had the opportunity yet to stub out these classes and their required methods.

One solution I used was to simply define the required method before the `require` statement:

```ruby
require 'spec_helper'

module These
  class Helpers
    def self.delegatable
      [:attribute]
    end
  end
end

require 'service'

describe My::Service do
  ...
end
```

But this can become unwieldable fast, and at this point I am doing RSpec's job.

Are there any better ways to solve this issue? Or should I just accept that in this case, the dependencies have to be loaded for the tests to work?